# How to navigate to viewcontrollers from expanded / nested UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Using **Alex Di Mango's** POPDownMenuTable-master setup expanding nested UITableviewCell and successfully functioning well in my project...But now the issue is how to navigate to other view controllers from the menu and nested / expanding submenu UITableviewcells...using ***didSelectRowAtIndexPth*** as everything programatically created..Please refer below code...

```
**POPDCell.h**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface POPDCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *separator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sepShadow;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *shadow;

@end
```

**POPDCell.h**

```
#import "POPDCell.h"

@implementation POPDCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
@end
```

---

```
POPDSampleViewController.m

#import "POPDSampleViewController.h"
#import "POPDViewController.h"

static NSString *kheader = @"menuSectionHeader";
static NSString *ksubSection = @"menuSubSection";

@interface POPDSampleViewController()<POPDDelegate> 

@end

@implementation POPDSampleViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    NSArray *sucSectionsA = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Personal Information",@"Emergency Contact", @"Family Physician", nil];
    NSArray *sucSectionsB = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Current Medications",@"Medical Details", nil];
    NSArray *sucSectionsC = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Appointments",@"Other Reminders", nil];
    NSArray *sucSectionsD = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Health Risk Assessment",@"Short HRA", nil];


    NSDictionary *section1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Dashboard", kheader, nil];

    NSDictionary *sectionA = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"My Profile", kheader,
                                    sucSectionsA, ksubSection,
                                    nil];

    NSDictionary *section2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"My BMI", kheader, nil];

    NSDictionary *sectionB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"My Medical Status", kheader,
                              sucSectionsB, ksubSection,
                              nil];

    NSDictionary *sectionC = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"My Health Planner", kheader,
                        sucSectionsC, ksubSection,
                        nil];
    NSDictionary *sectionD = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"My Health Assessment", kheader,
                              sucSectionsD, ksubSection,
                              nil];
    NSDictionary *section3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"My Wellness Tracker", kheader, nil];


    NSArray *menu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: section1, sectionA, section2, sectionB, sectionC, sectionD, section3, nil];
    POPDViewController *popMenu = [[POPDViewController alloc]initWithMenuSections:menu];
    popMenu.delegate = self;
    popMenu.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    //ios7 status bar
//     popMenu.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0);

    [self addChildViewController:popMenu];
    [self.view addSubview:popMenu.view];

}

#pragma mark POPDViewController delegate

-(void) didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath: %ld,%ld",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row);

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

---

```
**POPDViewController.h**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#ifndef MB_STRONG
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#define MB_STRONG strong
#else
#define MB_STRONG retain
#endif
#endif

#ifndef MB_WEAK
#if __has_feature(objc_arc_weak)
#define MB_WEAK weak
#elif __has_feature(objc_arc)
#define MB_WEAK unsafe_unretained
#else
#define MB_WEAK assign
#endif
#endif

@protocol POPDDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end


@interface POPDViewController : UITableViewController
- (id)initWithMenuSections:(NSArray *) menuSections;
@property (MB_WEAK) id<POPDDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

---

```
**POPDViewController.m**

#import "POPDViewController.h"
#import "POPDCell.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "POPDSampleViewController.h"



#define TABLECOLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
#define CELLSELECTED [UIColor colorWithRed:4.0/255.0 green:198.0/255.0 blue:251.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
#define SEPARATOR [UIColor colorWithRed:124.0/255.0 green:130.0/255.0 blue:131.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
#define SEPSHADOW [UIColor colorWithRed:80.0/255.0 green:97.0/255.0 blue:110.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
#define SHADOW [UIColor colorWithRed:69.0/255.0 green:84.0/255.0 blue:95.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
#define TEXT [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255.0 green:22.0/255.0 blue:121.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]

static NSString *kheader = @"menuSectionHeader";
static NSString *ksubSection = @"menuSubSection";

@interface POPDViewController ()
@property NSArray *sections;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *sectionsArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *showingArray;
@end


@implementation POPDViewController
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithMenuSections:(NSArray *) menuSections
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.sections = menuSections;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = inset;


//    [[UITableView appearance] setSeparatorColor:[UIColor grayColor]];


    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = ({
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 80.0f)];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-50, 0, 200, 80)];
        imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-hd.png"];
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        //        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
        imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        [view addSubview:imageView];
        view;
    });


    self.tableView.backgroundColor = TABLECOLOR;
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];

    self.tableView.frame = self.view.frame;

    self.sectionsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.showingArray = [NSMutableArray new];
   [self setMenuSections:self.sections];

}

- (void)setMenuSections:(NSArray *)menuSections{

    for (NSDictionary *sec in menuSections) {

        NSString *header = [sec objectForKey:kheader];
        NSArray *subSection = [sec objectForKey:ksubSection];

        NSMutableArray *section = [NSMutableArray new];
        [section addObject:header];

        for (NSString *sub in subSection) {
            [section addObject:sub];
        }
        [self.sectionsArray addObject:section];
        [self.showingArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{    
    return [self.sectionsArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    if (![[self.showingArray objectAtIndex:section]boolValue]) {

        return 1;
    }
    else{

        return [[self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section]count];;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row ==0){
    if([[self.showingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]boolValue]){
        [cell setBackgroundColor:CELLSELECTED];
    }else{
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"menuCell";
    #warning : Use here your custom cell, instead of POPDCell

    POPDCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (POPDCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"POPDCell" owner:self options:nil];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.labelText.text = [[self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.labelText.textColor = TEXT;
    cell.separator.backgroundColor = SEPARATOR;
    cell.sepShadow.backgroundColor = SEPSHADOW;
    cell.shadow.backgroundColor = SHADOW;

//    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if([[self.showingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]boolValue]){

        [self.showingArray setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.section];
    }else{
        [self.showingArray setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.section];
    }
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In didselectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   if (indexPath.row ==0) {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier0" sender:self];
   }else if(indexPath.row==1{
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier1" sender:self];
   }//and so on
}
```

depending on how many segues you have that could continue. In storyboard you need to increase the number of prototype cells by going to attributes inspector when selecting your tableView. You also need to control-click-drag to the viewControllers you wish to segue with and select push. Then name those identifiers "SegueIdentifer0"...

then you need a prepareForSeque method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier0"]) {
    NSLog(@"Segue1");
  }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier1"]){
      NSLog(@"Segue2");
   }
}
```

Comment: as i have not used any tabueviecontroller in storyboard...i could not connect with segue..i'll try with orxelm's method....

Answer (score 0):

You are not obligated to use segues, you can always initialize your viewcontrollers from code and then present them:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSString *identifier = @"";

    if (indexPath.row ==0) {
        identifier = @"VC1";
    }
    else if(indexPath.row==1) {
        identifier = @"VC2";
    }

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    [self.navigationController showViewController:viewController sender:NULL];
}
```